# Having a hard time using max_element (min_element also) on a multimap<Class object, enum>

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, multimap

I'm having a really hard time solving this problem. I want to find the max and min of my keys in my multimap (which happen to be objects of a class). By max and min I'm referring to my objects size member ONLY. I've made a comparator function, to pass it on the max_element(respectively min_element) functions, but I'm getting some error -- **invalid initialization of reference of type 'const CFile&' from expression of type 'std::pair < const CFile, CDirectory::Filetype>'**

I fixed this problem with my own implementation of min and max functions, but it just doesn't seem right to me. That's why I want to use the min/max_element algorithms...

Here is my sample program::

```
class CFile {
    string m_strFile;
    unsigned int m_size;
public:
    CFile () { m_strFile = ""; m_size = 0; }
    CFile (string name, int size ) { m_strFile = name; m_size = size; }
    string getFileName () const { return m_strFile; }
    int getFileSize () const { return m_size; }
    void setFileSize ( int size ) { m_size = size; }
    /* stream manipulating and overloading operators here */
static bool Greater(const CFile& obj1, const CFile& obj2) {
        return (obj1.getFileSize() > obj2.getFileSize());
}

bool operator< (CFile obj1, CFile obj2) {
    return obj1.getFileName()<obj2.getFileName();
}


class CDirectory {
    string m_strDirectory;
    enum class Filetype {
        Archive, Hidden, ReadOnly, System, FileNotSupported
    };
    Filetype filetype;
    multimap <CFile, Filetype> m_DirectoryMap;
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Filetype const type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
        case Filetype::Archive:
            os << "archive";
            break;
        case Filetype::Hidden:
            os << "hidden";
            break;
        case Filetype::ReadOnly:
            os << "read-only";
            break;
        case Filetype::System:
            os << "system";
            break;
        case Filetype::FileNotSupported:
            os << "not-supported";
            break;
        }
        return os;
    }
    CDirectory (string n) {
              fp.open (n, ios::in);
              string dirName, fileName,  fType;
              int fileSize;
              fp >> dirName;
              m_strDirectory = dirName;
              while (fp >> fileName >> fileSize >> fType) {
                      CFile obj (fileName, fileSize);
                       if (fType == "Archive")
                  filetype = Filetype::Archive;
              else if (fType == "Hidden")
                  filetype = Filetype::Hidden;
              else if (fType == "ReadOnly")
                  filetype = Filetype::ReadOnly;
              else if (fType == "System")
                  filetype = Filetype::System;
              else
                  filetype = Filetype::FileNotSupported;
              m_DirectoryMap.insert(pair<CFile, Filetype>(CFile(obj.getFileName(), obj.getFileSize()), Filetype(filetype)));
              }
              multimap<CFile, Filetype>::iterator p = m_DirectoryMap.begin();
              while ( p != m_DirectoryMap.end()) {
                cout << endl << p->first.getFileName() << '\t' << p->first.getFileSize() << '\t' << p->second << endl;
                ++p;
              }
    }
    void test() {
        std::multimap<CFile, Filetype>::iterator result;
        result = std::max_element(m_DirectoryMap.begin(), m_DirectoryMap.end(), Greater);
        std::cout << "max element: " << result->first.GetFileSize() << "\t" << result->first.GetFileName();
    }
};

int main () {
    CDirectory obj("test.txt");
    obj.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please reduce the example into a [mcve]? Note the "Minimal" part. File input, stream manipulators etc. have precious little to do with the problem you're describing.

Comment: Unrelated note: Having two (inconsistent!) operators `<` defined for a class (one at namespace scope and one in class) is *terrible* practice, and a disaster waiting to happen. Get rid of one of them (or both, even; comapring files for ordering is rather unintuitive).

Comment: Thank you, I will edit my original post. I'm having the global operator `<` because (somehow) I can't seem to insert my multimap pairs (from my second class constructor) if I don't have that.

Comment: If you remove them both, you'll have to provide a suitable comparator to the map. BTW, the problem with the in-class `<` was probably that it wasn't `const`, and so couldn't be used on the map's keys (which are `const`).

Comment: Yes, it seems like that was the problem... I made it const and removed the global one - now everything is fine. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comapre function for [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) needs to have a signature like

```
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

Where

> The types `Type1` and `Type2` must be such that an object of type `ForwardIt` can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both of them. ​

Since you are using

```
std::max_element(m_DirectoryMap.begin(), m_DirectoryMap.end(), Greater);
```

The type being passed to `Greater` is `*std::multimap<CFile, Filetype>::iterator` which is a `std::pair < const CFile, CDirectory::Filetype>` not a `const CFile& obj1` like `Greater` wants.

You need to write a function in the that takes two `std::pair < const CFile, CDirectory::Filetype>` and compares them.  A function that should work could look like

```
static bool GreaterPair(const std::pair<const CFile, CDirectory::Filetype> & lhs,
                 const std::pair<const CFile, CDirectory::Filetype> & rhs)
{
    return Greater(lhs.first, rhs.first);
}
```

You also have a typo in

```
std::cout << "max element: " << result->first.GetFileSize() << "\t" << result->first.GetFileName();
```

The function is `getFileSize()` not `GetFileSize()`.  Change it to

```
std::cout << "max element: " << result->first.getFileSize() << "\t" << result->first.getFileName();
```

Comment: thanks for your help. When I try to call the max_element with GreaterPair passed as comp I get some ` no matching function for call to 'max_element(std::multimap<CFile, CDirectory::Filetype>::iterator, std::multimap<CFile, CDirectory::Filetype>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'` . Any thoughts on that ? :(

Comment: @hopittyhop I forgot the `static` keyword.  Try that.

Comment: well it passes that line now. But I'm getting another error, at the line where I print the max element. It's the 3rd line in my test() function. error: 'const class CFile' has no member named 'GetFileSize'. Isn't `result` a pair with 2 objects of class CFile?

Comment: @hopittyhop I forgot to mention that.  You have a typo.  I added it into the answer.

Comment: @hopittyhop No problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103137/discussion-between-hopittyhop-and-nathanoliver).

Answer (score 2):

min_element / max_element operate on containers and are not map aware. They will iterate through all the elements and find the one you're looking for. The issue is that when you have a multimap the element type is `pair<const CFile, FileType>` not just `CFile`. Just modify your `Greater` function to work with the pair, and return the result of comparing the `CFile` from the pair.

If you want a more general/shorter solution you could define an alias for `std::multimap<Cfile, FileType>::value_type` which will be the pair I mentioned.

Should look something like this

```
static bool Greater(const std::pair<const CFile, FileType>& a,
                    const std::pair<const CFile, FileType>& b) {
    return (a.first.getFileSize() > b.first.getFileSize());
}
```

Comment: How would the modified version of Greater (comparing a CFile size member from the pair) would look like? I have no idea. :(

Answer (score 0):

Should be more efficient to use multimap::upper_bound in a loop.

Comment: Isn't the best way to use a compare function, to compare the objects in the multimap?

Comment: The compare function is necessary for sorting the keys in any map/multimap. So if you have a map/multimap, you already have a compare function.

Comment: But can I, for example, order the multimap pairs by fileName and have some function that returns min and max (where I pass a compare function to compare by fileSize?

Comment: Aha, now I see - your map is ordered by the CFile < operator, which compares file names. So in this case, using map::upper_bound is not directly applicable. And to answer the original question, you need to have an operator/comparator fcn that takes pairs of CFile, Filetype, not a comparator that only takes CFile.